# Residual Connected Apps left after managed package install

Tags: connected-apps, delete-managed-package

We have a customer who uninstalled our 1GP from their org. After the package uninstallation and deletion of the related data, they still have two Connected Apps in their org that were part of the 1GP.

The only reason we know this is because they appeared as rows for this query in the **Developer Console**:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM ConnectedApplication
```

If we go to **Setup** > **App Manager**, the two connected apps do not appear in the list.

The problem is that the customer cannot install our 2GP because the ConnectedApps associated with it have the same API name as the ConnectedApps in the 1GP.

Questions:

1. Can the two rows for these be deleted from the Developer Console? There is a **Delete Row** button.
2. If #1 is possible, are there any potential ramifications for doing this?
3. If #1 is not possible, can Salesforce Support do it on behalf of the customer?